# "$X$" with an "$n$" in the bottom right: what is it called and how do I type it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, terminology

From time to time, i have come across the symbol x with a little n in the bottom right, similar to aleph numbers. What is it called, and how do I type it?

Comment: What do you mean? Like $x_n$?

Comment: $x_n$ is typically used to denote the $n$th value of $x$ when we have a list or sequence of values. One pronounciation can be "x sub n" and can be written as `$x_n$`

Comment: Or like $\times_n$?

Comment: Thank you. I knew it's function, but not it's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just mean a subscript?  E.g. $a_1$, $a_2$, ..., $a_n$.

They are called subscripts.  You can say "a subscript 1", "a sub 1" or, if the context is obvious, just "a 1".

It is easy to type those in MathJax.  They should surrounded by \$ signs as usual.  For $a_1$, I used a_1.  If the subscript is more than one character, you need to use { and }.  E.g. $a_{i_1}$ for which I used a_{i_1}.

Superscripts (e.g. exponentiation) are similar but use ^ in place of _.  E.g. For $a^2$ I used a^2.  Again, use { and } if there is more than one character e.g. $a^{x + y}$ is a^{x + y}.

Comment: Now I just have to make it work on the calculator I'm using.

Comment: Ah, that is a different matter and I won't be able to help.  For a start, we would need to know which calculator but I don't know whether calculator help is allowed here.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: You can do that in [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hq71piovab). You use underscore.

Comment: I tried that, I can type it, but I apparently need to learn how to write out subscripts in general.